# OwlFonk/OwlCarousel is down ? Where to map the dependency in our bower.json

Tags: git, carousel, bower, owl-carousel

The official github repo of owlCarousel gives 404. No idea if the owner's account is down or what.

Our Atlassian Bamboo build is failing, since the process use live clone mentioned in the Repo. I need to know where I could legally clone it and resolve the issue.

Any feedback appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I was about to post this, but I have a Fix for now, taking it into account.

use this alias (i created)
https://shahzadns@bitbucket.org/shahzadns/owlfonk-owlcarousel.git

Example:
inside your bower.json > dependencies
...
"owlCarousel": "https://shahzadns@bitbucket.org/shahzadns/owlfonk-owlcarousel.git",
...

Note: the version uploaded there is 1.3.2 (this is the latest i had, lol)

hope this helps.
Enjoy !